# NodeJS why is object[0] returning '{' instead of the first property from this json object?

Tags: node.js, json, regex

So I have to go through a bunch of code to get some data from an iframe. the iframe has a lot of data but in there is an object called '_name'. the first key of name is 'extension_id' and its value is a big long string. the json object is enclosed in apostrophes. I have tried removing the apostrophes but still instead of 'extension_id_output' I get a single curly bracket. the json object looks something like this

```
Frame {
   ...
   ...
   _name: '{"extension_id":"a big huge string that I need"} "a bunch of other stuff":"this is a valid json object as confirmed by jsonlint", "globalOptions":{"crev":"1.2.50"}}}'
 }
```

it's a whole big ugly paragraph but I really just need the extension_id. so this is the code I'm currently using after attempt 100 or whatever.

```
var frames = await page.frames();
// I'm using puppeteer for this part but I don't think that's relevant overall.

var thing = frames[1]._name; 
console.log(frames[1])
// console.log(thing)

thing.replace(/'/g, '"')
// this is to remove the apostrophes from the outside of the object. I thought that would change things before. it does not. still outputs a single {
JSON.parse(thing)
console.log(thing[0])
```

instead of getting `a big huge string that I need` or whatever is written in `extension_id`. I get a `{`. that's it. I think that is because the whole object starts with a curly bracket. this is confirmed to me because `console.log(thing[2])` prints `e`. so what's going on? jsonlint says this is a valid json object but maybe it's just a big string and I should be doing some kind of split to grab whaat's between the first `:` and the first `,`. I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two reasons:

1. `object[0]` doesn't return the value an object's "first property", it returns the value of the property with the name `"0"`, if any (there probably isn't in your object); and
2. Because it's **JSON**, and when you're dealing with JSON in JavaScript code, you are by definition dealing with a **string**. ([More here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247).) If you want to deal with the object that the JSON describes, parse it.

Here's an example of parsing it and getting the value of the `extension_id` property from it:

```
const parsed = JSON.parse(frames[1]._name);
console.log(parsed.extension_id); // The ID
```